# Multiple tag search in an associative table scheme

Tags: php, mysql, tags

I'm working with your standard three table tag setup

```
item_table
 item_id
 item_name

tag_table
 tag_id
 tag_name

tag_map
 map_id
 tag_id
 item_id
```

How this works should be obvious to anyone who has used a similar scheme for their tagging architecture, now, using this scheme I have a scenario in which I need to print the results of the item_table that match multiple tags, meaning they must have each tag presented to match and print the item from the item table, something written theoretically like this

```
SELECT i.item_id, i.item_name, t.tag_id, t.tag_name, m.tag_id, m.item_id FROM item_table AS i
JOIN tag_table AS t ON t.tag_id = m.tag_id
JOIN tag_map AS m ON m.item_id = i.item_id
WHERE t.tag_name = 'tag_one'
AND t.tag_name = 'tag_two'
```

And the desired output would be something like

item 1 (because the records for item 1 have assigned both tag_one and tag_two in the tag map)
item 2 (ditto)
(but not item 3 because it only has tag_one, or none of the tags)

Of course I know this wouldn't work, and why, I merely provided the mis-formed example to highlight what I'm trying to accomplish.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: it should be OR in t.tag_name case.It can't have both right.

Comment: You misinterpret what I'm trying to accomplish, I'm aware it can't have both right under the current setup, that's why I'm asking how I would go about checking the map table for item_id's only if there are rows for each of the tag_ids in the statement also in the table. --even if it means that I have to redo my table scheme to support this

Comment: I should also clarify, what I mean is, if I can't manage to do this under my current table scheme, I'm willing to change it in anyway to allow the matching requires, it seems highly unlikely that a tagging scheme as popular as this wouldn't have some method of matching two tags for an entry instead of just one or another, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
SELECT i.item_id, i.item_name, t.tag_id, t.tag_name, m.tag_id, m.item_id 
FROM item_table AS i
JOIN tag_map AS m ON m.item_id = i.item_id
JOIN tag_table AS t ON t.tag_id = m.tag_id AND t.tag_name IN('tag1','tag2')
WHERE m.map_id NOT IN (SELECT m1.map_id FROM tag_map m1,item_table i1, tag_table t1
WHERE m1.item_id = i1.item_id AND m1.tag_id = t1.tag_id AND t1.tag_name IN('tag1','tag2')
GROUP BY m1.item_id HAVING COUNT(m1.item_id) <2)
```

Comment: It works exactly as intended, and being that I understand it, it's actually incredibly helpful insight as to how it should have been done, thank you very much!

Comment: I have not tested this code but i think the AND after the second JOIN and before the WHERE clausole is not correct. You agree?